# How to use Laravel 9 Notification Events

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-notification, laravel-events

I am using laravel 9 queue notification. I want to see if the emails are sent successfully or not.
I have read and executed the laravel documentation notification events

```
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#notification-events
```

but when I run my code, laravel is not getting into the event/listener. I think I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what!?

**Notification Command**

```
foreach ($this->emails as $email) 
{
   Notification::route('mail', $email)->notify(new OrderConfirmationNotification());
}
```

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $listen = [
        NotificationSending::class => [
            CheckNotificationStatus::class,
        ],
        NotificationSent::class => [
            LogNotification::class
        ]
    ];
```

**CheckNotificationStatus.php**

```
public function __construct() {}

public function handle(NotificationSending $event)
{
  dd($event);
}
```

**LogNotification.php**

```
public function __construct()
{}

public function handle(NotificationSent $event)
{
 dd($event);
}
```

I hope you can help me with it.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to run php artisan queue:work